# How can I delete and disable an input element?

Tags: reactjs

This is my App

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Input from "./components/Input";

function App() {
  const [newRow, setNewRow] = useState([]);
  
  
  const addRow = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setNewRow(
      newRow.concat(<Input key={newRow.length} myKey={newRow.length} />)
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={addRow}>Add row</button>
      <ul>
        <Input key={newRow.length} myKey={newRow.length}/>
        {newRow}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And this is my Input component

```
import "./Input.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";


const Input = (props) => {
    const [updatedList, setUpdatedList] = useState([])
  const deleteRow = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const key = props.myKey;
    setUpdatedList(updatedList.splice(key, 1));
    console.log(updatedList);
  };
  const disableRow = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };
  return (
    <li className="item">
      <select>
        <option value="+">+</option>
        <option value="-">-</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" />
      <button onClick={deleteRow}>Delete</button>
      <button onClick={disableRow}>Disable</button>
    </li>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

I guess I'm supposed to delete and disable the List HTML element through its key but I'm getting an empty array when I console.log(updatedList). So how can I delete from the original array in the parent component from the child component?

Comment: Please read this article about how to update react state arrays. https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-state-array-add-update-remove/

Answer (score 1):

Add a `deleteRow` function to your `App` component.

```js
// App.js
const deleteRow = (key) => {
  setNewRow(newRow.filter(input => input.key != key));
}
```

Pass it as a prop to your child component and call it onClick.

```js
// Input.js
const deleteRow = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const key = props.myKey;
    props.deleteRow(key);
  };
```

`updatedList` is unnecessary as you already have an array in the parent component.

Comment: I tried this solution, when I add three rows and click delete on the second row, it deletes the second and the third.

Comment: @leenades have you verified that no `<Input>` has the same key twice?

Comment: Yes, If i console log newRow I get this:

0: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), key: '0', ref: null, props: {…}, type: ƒ, …}
1: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), key: '1', ref: null, props: {…}, type: ƒ, …}
2: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), key: '2', ref: null, props: {…}, type: ƒ, …}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at context: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html
It could help with your issue

Answer (score 0):

The `const [updatedList, setUpdatedList] = useState([])` is complete redundant. Instead, **Lift the state** by passing the `newRow` and the `setNewRow` directly into to the input component via props and manipulate it from there. Or pass in a function that manipulates it into the input component.

Also, you shouldn't call `splice` directly on the `updatedList` because it changes the contents of the list, and splice is an array which is a reference type.

It might be better to use `filter(() => boolean)` which returns a new array instead of mutation the current on. Or creating a new variable,
`const updatedListCopy = [...updatedList]`
and then call splice on that.

Answer (score 0):

You should write `deleteRow()` as props from app.js
When you declare `deleteRow()` inside of individual Input component, that could not manipulate or update the parent values.
`disableRow()` is only usable for individual `Input` component, while `deleteRow()` relative with Parent `newRow`
App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Input from "./components/Input";

function App() {
  const [newRow, setNewRow] = useState([]);
  
  
  const addRow = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setNewRow(
      newRow.concat(<Input key={newRow.length} myKey={newRow.length} deleteRow={deleteRow} />)
    );
  };
  const deleteRow = (key) => {
   console.log(key)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={addRow}>Add row</button>
      <ul>
        <Input key={newRow.length} myKey={newRow.length}/>
        {newRow}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In your component

```
import "./Input.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";


const Input = (props) => {
    const [updatedList, setUpdatedList] = useState([]) 
    const disableRow = (event) => {
     event.preventDefault();
    };
    return (
     <li className="item">
      <select>
        <option value="+">+</option>
        <option value="-">-</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" />
      <button onClick={()=>props.deleteRow(props.key)}>Delete</button>
      <button onClick={disableRow}>Disable</button>
     </li>
   );
 };

export default Input;
```